# Jenkins maven Unable to locate the Javac compiler in JDK

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, compiler-errors

**Problem :** Unable to build spring maven project using Jenkins with JDK 1.8

**Description** : Im using Jenkins to build my spring project managed by Maven.I have configured Java 1.7 and 1.8 in Jenkins using the JDK Installations options. when selecting  Java 1.7 in the build configuration and running the build, build process is success. But when i select Java 1.8 in the build configuration and running the build, build process gets failed.

> ****Below is the jenkins console output****

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\anonymous\.jenkins\jobs\springsecuritysampleproject1\workspace
Updating file:///C:/DevEnv/Repositories/LocalSVNServerRepo/root/springsecuritysample/trunk at revision '2016-01-13T13:35:52.488 +0530'
U         src\main\java\org\springframework\security\sample\HomeController.java
At revision 21
Parsing POMs
[workspace] $ C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java -cp C:\Users\anonymous\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\ProjectTools\Apache_Maven_3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\ProjectTools\Apache_Maven_3.3.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\ProjectTools\Apache_Maven_3.3.3 C:\Users\anonymous\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.53.2.jar C:\Users\anonymous\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar C:\Users\anonymous\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 52876
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\anonymous\.jenkins\jobs\springsecuritysampleproject1\workspace\pom.xml install
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\anonymous\.jenkins\jobs\springsecuritysampleproject1\workspace\pom.xml to org.springframework.security/sample/1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/sample-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
Sending e-mails to: test@test.com
channel stopped
Archiving artifacts
Sending e-mails to: test@test.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

*

> I also ran Maven manually with Java 1.7 and no issues observerd. But
>   when i ran the same with Java 1.8 and redirected the output to file,
>   found the below error

*

```
INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\DevEnv\STSWorkspaces\springsecuritysample\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
**[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :** 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.640 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-13T13:40:34+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/487M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

JAVA_HOME variable is correctly pointing to the JDK 1.8 installation home directory and the bin folder is also added to the path

echo %JAVA_HOME% results in C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_20

When changed the JAVA_HOME variable to point to Java 1.7, build is running normally and no errors

Comment: Just to eliminate any doubt, there is indeed a jdk installed under `C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_20` and when pointing `JAVA_HOME` to it, running `javac -version` yields the correct result, right?

Comment: Yes..Running the command C:\Users\anonymous>javac -version
results in the output -- > javac 1.8.0_20

Comment: After a few hours of debugging on how maven obtains the tools.jar to launch the sun's Main class, got a custom log outputs for both success (using JDK 1.7) and failure (using JDK 1.8) build runs as below

Comment: Success (build using JDK 1.7)
[INFO] toolsJar file C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\..\lib\tools.jar
[INFO] Adding url  file:/C:/DevEnv/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/../lib/tools.jar

Comment: Failure (build using JDK 1.8)
[INFO] toolsJar file C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\..\lib\tools.jar

Comment: From the above for JDK 1.8 in the location for tools jar file the "jre" part is somehow missing and hence the compilation error.
But i dont know why the "jre" is ignored while running with JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

> Root Cause

when debugged, it ended up in the file JavacCompiler.java of artifact plexus-compiler-javac. The line System.getProperty( "java.home" ) in the compile process outputs differently for Java 8 and Java 7

Java 7 - C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre

Java 8 - C:\DevEnv\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_20

> Worked Solution :

Re-installation of Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Launch the slave through `cmd` but dont type `"java -jar slave.jar ....."`, rather mention the complete path of `java.exe` as `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" -jar slave.jar ......`